# PHP recursion not going back to foreach loop

Tags: php, recursion

Need some guidance with some PHP recursion, I'm looping through some data comparing it against a Map, and if a form (in the data) has a subform it needs to be added to the DB with the parents forms ID.

All seems to be working except a subform is an array as there can be multiple subforms of the same type.

Heres a brief structure:

```
Parent[0]

SF_1[0]

   _SF_2[0]
   _SF_2[1]
   _SF_2[n]

SF_1[1]

SF_2[0]

SF_n[0]
```

So I add the parent in a separate function, then start the subform recursion (this bit works fine):

```
private function add_form_records($_data, $map)
{
    $form = new FormItem(); 

    foreach($map["fields"] as $item) {
        $key = $item->field;
        if(array_key_exists($key, $_data))
        {
            $form->column_data->$key = $_data[$key];
        }
    }

    $form->list_name = $map["sp_list"];
    $form->form_id = $this->id_count;
    $form->__metadata->type = $this->get_list_id($form->list_name);
    //Add the form to SP and get the ID back for the subforms
    $id = $this->add_record($form); 

    foreach($map["subforms"] as $key=>$value) {
        $this->add_subform_records($_data[$key], $value, $form->form_id);
    }
}
```

Then heres the function that gets called to add the subforms and then call itself it the subform has subforms:

```
private function add_subform_records($_data, $_map, $_parent_id)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_data); ++$i) {
            $form = new FormItem(); 

            foreach($_map["fields"] as $fieldItem)
            {
                $key = $fieldItem->field;

                if(array_key_exists($key, $_data[$i]))
                {
                    $form->column_data->$key = $_data[$i][$key];
                }
            }

            $form->parent_id = $_parent_id; 
            $form->list_name = $_map["sp_list"];
            $form->form_id = $this->id_count;
            $form->form_name = $_map["subform_name"];

            $form->__metadata->type = $this->get_list_id($form->list_name);
            $id = $this->add_record($form); 

            if(array_key_exists('subforms', $_map))
            {
                foreach($_map["subforms"] as $key=>$value) {
                    foreach($_data as $subform)
                    {
                        if(array_key_exists($key, $subform))
                        {
                            $this->add_subform_records($subform[$key],$value, $form->form_id);
                        }
                    }
                }   
            } 
    }

}
```

So the problem is it adds the first subform, goes to add its subforms (and does) but doesn't come back to the `for ($i = 0; $i < count($_data); ++$i)` to add the others.

Thanks!

$_data

```
array ( '_submit' => 'submit', '_submittedTime' => '1386837565194', '_submittedTimezoneOffset' => '11', 'ReportedBy' => 'test', 'DateAndTime' => '2013-12-12 19:38', 'Location' => 'hello', 'ClientName' => 'my', 'DiscussionType' => 'Meeting', 'SF_Attendees' => array ( 0 => array ( 'AttendeeName' => 'name', 'Company' => 'is', 'SF_Trip' => array ( 0 => array ( 'test1' => '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', '_action' => 'add', 'test1_mimetype' => 'image/jpeg', 'test2' => '', 'test3' => '', ), ), '_action' => 'add', ), 1 => array ( 'AttendeeName' => 'S', 'Company' => 'T', '_action' => 'add', ), ), 'ReasonforMeeting' => 'test', 'FollowUp' => '2013-12-19 19:38', 'UserEmail' => 'dev@dev.com', 'EmailCopyTo' => 's@s.com', 'SF_Attend' => array ( 0 => array ( 'AttendeeName' => 'test', 'Company' => 'test', '_action' => 'add', ), ), '_action' => 'add', '_uuid' => '63FD4677-C72A-4F1A-B711-963849B6840B', '_DateAndTime_time_offset' => '+11:00', '_FollowUp_time_offset' => '+11:00', )
```

$map

```
array ( 'sp_list' => 'ClientMeetingNote', 'fields' => array ( 0 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'ReportedBy', 'type' => 'textbox', )), 1 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'DateAndTime', 'type' => 'timestamp', )), 2 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'Location', 'type' => 'textbox', )), 3 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'ClientName', 'type' => 'textbox', )), 4 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'DiscussionType', 'type' => 'radio', )), 5 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'ReasonforMeeting', 'type' => 'text_area', )), 6 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'FollowUp', 'type' => 'timestamp', )), 7 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'Signature', 'type' => 'sketch_signature', )), 8 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'UserEmail', 'type' => 'email', )), 9 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'EmailCopyTo', 'type' => 'email', )), ), 'subforms' => array ( 'SF_Attendees' => array ( 'subform_name' => 'SF_Attendees', 'subform_data_name' => 'SF_Attendees', 'sp_list' => 'Attendees', 'fields' => array ( 0 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'AttendeeName', 'type' => 'textbox', )), 1 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'Company', 'type' => 'textbox', )), ), 'subforms' => array ( 'SF_Trip' => array ( 'subform_name' => 'SF_Trip', 'subform_data_name' => 'SF_Trip', 'sp_list' => 'Trip', 'fields' => array ( 0 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'test1', 'type' => 'camera', )), 1 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'test2', 'type' => 'image_library', )), 2 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'test3', 'type' => 'file_upload', )), ), ), ), ), 'SF_Attend' => array ( 'subform_name' => 'SF_Attend', 'subform_data_name' => 'SF_Attendees', 'sp_list' => 'Attendees', 'fields' => array ( 0 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'AttendeeName', 'type' => 'textbox', )), 1 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'Company', 'type' => 'textbox', )), ), 'subforms' => array ( 'SF_Trip' => array ( 'subform_name' => 'SF_Trip', 'subform_data_name' => 'SF_Trip', 'sp_list' => 'Trip', 'fields' => array ( 0 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'test1', 'type' => 'camera', )), 1 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'test2', 'type' => 'image_library', )), 2 => SchemaItem::__set_state(array( 'field' => 'test3', 'type' => 'file_upload', )), ), ), ), ), ), )
```

Comment: If you're not getting back to the loop, you must be recursing infinitely, since there's no way out of the without continuing the iterations. Can you post `var_export()` of your data so we can try your functions?

Comment: Hey @Barmar I've attached to the original post, when you run this you'll notice it adds the subform records except the Attendee form with Name = 's' and Company = 't'

Comment: Hmm, this is going to be trickier than I thought, because there are dependencies on other functions and properties in your class.

Comment: those can be hard coded, as they just return strings, they're not influenced by the recursive functions. Appreciate your help @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!! Had to restructure code as it was looping through the data twice, recursion was working fine I was sending it the wrong data.